# Запрос GET с авторизацией по HTTPS в Android Studio

Tags: авторизация, get, https

Пытаюсь получить данные с сайта, отправляя ему запрос такого вида:

```
class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String[] resultat = new String[20]; try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://myhost.com/");
        httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ");
        httpget.setHeader("username", "xxx");
        httpget.setHeader("password","yyy");
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                instream.close();
                resultat[0] = result;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return null;
    }   return resultat;  
}
```

А в ответ никаких данных, в LogCat нашел это:

```
01-26 13:15:49.435 23356-23646/com.catsoft.kursuzb I/System.out: [CDS]close[40945]     
01-26 13:15:49.435 23356-23646/com.catsoft.kursuzb I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:40945]   
01-26 13:15:49.440 23356-23646/com.catsoft.kursuzb W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <myhost.com> != <*.hosting.reg.ru> OR <*.hosting.reg.ru> OR <hosting.reg.ru>
```

Answer (score 3):

Запрос аутентифицируется не заголовками `username` и `password`, которые вы пытаетесь добавить, а правильными данными в заголовке `Authorization`. И если нужна только `Basic` аутентификация, то должно сработать что-то вроде

```
httpget.setHeader("Authorization",
  "Basic " + Base64.encode("xxx:yyy".getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

UPD: Проблема с запросом в том, что имя хоста в запросе не соответствует теме (имени) сертификата (и альтернативным именам, если есть).

Comment: спасибо разобрался c https помог код  HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
                socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));

Comment: SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(httpclient.getParams(), registry);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, httpclient.getParams());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);